# Git Flag Syntax: why do some flags have -one dash and some have --two?

Tags: git, syntax, flags

I am learning Git and have been [unable](http://www.google.com/search?q=git%20two%20dashes%20flag) [to](http://www.google.com/search?q=git%20flag%20option%20dashes) [find](http://www.google.com/search?q=git+"two+dashes") [any](http://www.google.com/search?q=git%20why%20some%20flags%20two%20dashes) [explanation](http://gitref.org/) [of](http://www.google.com/search?q=git%20flag%20syntax) [the](http://www.google.com/search?q=git%20dash%20syntax) [flag](http://www.google.com/search?q=git+"flag+syntax") [syntax](http://www.google.com/search?q=git+"dash+syntax").

I'm not referring to the "bare double dashes"

`--`

which, as we know, indicate that what follows is not an option. I'm referring to various actual flags which sometimes have one dash, and sometimes have two.

`git log -2 -p -U1 --graph`

What is the difference between a flag with one dash and two dashes? What does the double dash indicate?

For example, the following two flags are identical, ([according to this](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_options)):

```
-q
--quiet
```

Why the different number of dashes? What if I put the wrong number?

Comment: Or what about options that require no dashes (ie, git stash list)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My understanding is that git follows the 'standard' Linux convention for flags. That is:

- one dash for 'short' flags: generally one character flags, but sometimes flags with a single character, then further characters which represent a parameter to the flag (e.g. `git log -SFoo`, in which `Foo` is a parameter to the `-S` flag). These flags may or may not be abbreviated forms of other, longer flags.
- Two dashes for 'long' flags: multi-character flags which are usually an English word. If these flags receive parameters, it is separated from the flag by an `=` sign (e.g. `git log --author=Peter`).

This is the 'why': it is a convention which is embedded in the Linux world. Git comes from this world, so it follows the convention. The 'two dashes for a long flag, one for a short flag' rule should guide you as to how many dashes to use for a flag.

As for why there are duplicate short and long flags, such as `--quiet` and `-q`, it's just to provide the option of either mnemonic convenience or terseness. `--quiet` is easier to remember, but `-q` is quicker to type and mentally parse if you're used to it. For instance, I type `git commit -m "...blah"` so frequently it would get on my nerves if I had to double the length of my command every time by entering `git commit --message='...blah'`.

I haven't come across any git flags which behave differently given two dashes and one dash, so generally if you enter two dashes for a one-dash flag or *vice versa*, nothing irreparably bad will happen, git will just complain about your flags and do nothing.

Of course, git has a vast number of commands, each with a vast number of flags, so it is possible that there are exceptions to all these rules. They should generally hold though.

Comment: The long flags are also often preferred in scripts, since someone reading a script instantly has a good idea of what `--quiet` does, but something like `-q` will likely need to be looked up to understand what it does.

Comment: Traditionally short flags can be bundled; for example `ls -ltr` is equivalent to `ls -l -t -r`. But git doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: @KeithThompson Some git commands do support bundling, such as `git grep`. I don't know the rationale for supporting or not supporting it for a given command, though.

Comment: @Peter: I suspect there is no rationale.